# Simple way of creating array from key and certain sub array values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a source array that looks like this:

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'foo_bar',
        'baz' => 'foo_baz'
    ),
    'fizz' => array(
        'bar' => 'fizz_bar',
        'baz' => 'fizz_baz'
    )
);
```

I would like to create another array by selecting a key: `bar` or `baz`, which will return all of the root keys with the values of the specified key?

```
some_function($data, 'bar') == array(
    'foo' => 'foo_bar',
    'fizz' => 'fizz_bar'
);
```

Is there a built-in php function(s) to generate the following results without doing my own loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'foo_bar',
        'baz' => 'foo_baz'
    ),
    'fizz' => array(
        'bar' => 'fizz_bar',
        'baz' => 'fizz_baz'
    )
);
```

To select `bar`:

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_keys($data),
    array_column($data, 'bar')
);
```

Here's an example:

```
php > var_dump(array_combine(array_keys($data), array_column($data, 'bar')));
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(7) "foo_bar"
  ["fizz"]=>
  string(8) "fizz_bar"
}
```

Note that `array_column()` was introduced in PHP 5.5.

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer, so if you don't mind, I just added the example I was going to show and the note about 5.5+. Rollback if you don't like :)